# google cloud storage Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream when downloading file larger than chunksize with java api

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to download reviews from the play store which are accessible in a bucket using the java api (details at the end of the message). For review files which when compressed are larger than the chunk size i get the following exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:116)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:51)
at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:94)
at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:63)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpDownloader.java:247)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:199)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:553)
at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(Storage.java:4540)
at com.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get$executeMediaAndDownloadTo.call(Unknown Source)
```

The code snipped i'm using is:

```
private void saveObject(StorageObject object) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Getting object data");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream (new File(object.getName()));

        Storage.Objects.Get getObject =
            storage.objects().get("pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXX", object.getName());

        // setting the chunksize to a small value fails pretty much on all files
        getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(false).setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.MINIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE)

        // setting the chunksize to larger value allows me to download some of the files but fails on larger ones
        //getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(false).setChunkSize(MediaHttpDownloader.MAXIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE)


        getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error downloading " + object.getName());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can download the files using gsutil so it seems an issue which the chunking implementation inside MediaHttpDownloader.

I'm using java 7 and the following libs

```
compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.19.0'
compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.19.0'
compile group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-storage', version: 'v1beta2-rev56-1.19.0'
```

Also i am using groovy but don't see how this would affect the issue since the error is inside the google lib.

thanks for any help

andre

Comment: I have managed to work around the problem by setting the chunksize higher the the maximum chunksize using refection to bypass the check. It seems to work...
`Field field = getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().getClass().getDeclaredField("chunkSize");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader(), MediaHttpDownloader.MAXIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE * 10);`

Comment: That's an interesting problem. I see you're using Google Cloud Storage's JSON API v1beta2. Does the same problem happen if you use v1?